# EF Core - How to configure a required Foreign Key without a cascaded delete

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm getting troubles with quite a simple thing. (Entity Framework Core 5)

I wrote following configuration class for a base model from which several child classes are derived.

Models:

```cs
abstract public class RecordBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Item : RecordBase
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[NotMapped]
public abstract class LineBase : RecordBase
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemTransaction> ItemTransactions { get; set; } = new Collection<ItemTransaction>();
    public virtual ProductDim ProductDim { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class OrderLineBase : LineBase
{
    public string OrderNum { get; set; }
}

public abstract class JournalLineBase : LineBase
{
    public string JournalNum { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrderLine : OrderLineBase
{
    public string CustomerNum { get; set; }
}

public class PurchOrderLine : OrderLineBase
{
    public string CustomerNum { get; set; }
}

public class WmsJournalLine : JournalLineBase
{
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTransaction : RecordBase
{
    public DateTime TransDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual LineBase Line { get; set; }
    public string Reference{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductDim : RecordBase
{
    public int Configuration { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LineBase> LineBases { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm defining the relation to the ProductDim Table , which must not be nullable.
So I set up the relation make it `IsRequired()` and set the `DeleteBehavior` to `Restrict`.

```cs
class LineBaseConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : LineBase
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> modelBuilder)
    {        
        modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.ProductDim)
                    .WithMany(x => (ICollection<TEntity>)x.LineBases)
                    .HasForeignKey("ProductDimId")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);       
    }
}
```

The configuration will be applied to the child models of my `LineBase` model:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    ...
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<SalesOrderLine>(new LineBaseConfiguration<SalesOrderLine>());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<WmsJournalLine>(new LineBaseConfiguration<WmsJournalLine>());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<PurchOrderLine>(new LineBaseConfiguration<PurchOrderLine>());
    ...
}
```

Now when I add the migration to my project the foreign key is generated as `ReferentialAction.Cascade`.

Migration output:

```cs
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_PurchOrderLine_ProductDim_ProductDimId",
    table: "PurchOrderLine",
    column: "ProductDimId",
    principalTable: "ProductDim",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_SalesOrderLine_ProductDim_ProductDimId",
    table: "SalesOrderLine",
    column: "ProductDimId",
    principalTable: "ProductDim",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_WmsJournalLine_ProductDim_ProductDimId",
    table: "WmsJournalLine",
    column: "ProductDimId",
    principalTable: "ProductDim",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Only if i remove the `IsRequired()` from my model configuration. The correct RefrentialAction is generated. But then I've made the foreign key property nullable, which I have to avoid.

In this case the migration generates multiple cascades paths. So it is wothless, due i can't apply it to my database.

So is there any other way to get my ForeignKey field was a non-nullable and a correct delete action?

Comment: EF Core 5 manage the new null reference system, maybe you can try declare `LineBase.ProductDim` as nullable : `public virtual ProductDim? ProductDim { get; set; }`

Comment: But I want the opposite: LineBase.ProductDim should never be null. I tried your solution, but I didn't work either.

Comment: What is the expected deleted action?

Comment: Any kind of NO ACTION. I would prefer a Restrict or ClientNoAction.

I tried to iterate manually through the relationships and set the properties. Which would work as expected, but it seems to be a very ugly solution

`foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => typeof(LineBase).IsAssignableFrom(t.ClrType)).SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys().Where(fk => fk.IsRequired).ToList()))
            {
                relationship.IsRequired = true;
                relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.ClientNoAction;
            }`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but `IsRequired` add the foreign key in the entity. All modification do on the foreign key builder (like `OnDelete`) don't impact the foreign key because it is already build and added in entity. This sound like a bug.

The solution(hack?) is to call `IsRequired` at last :

```cs
modelBuilder.HasOne(x => x.ProductDim)
            .WithMany(x => (ICollection<TEntity>)x.LineBases)
            .HasForeignKey("ProductDimId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired(); // At last
```

Comment: How did you find this hack(?)  +1

Comment: @atiyar, [EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore) is open source. It's funny to explore the project.